# Слово "лечитесь"

Tags: грамматика

Интересует, как проверить последнюю Е (знаю, что 2-е спряжение).

Answer (score 1):

1. **Начнем с информации** (возможно, автор вопроса всё это знает)

Слово ***лечитесь***  связано с двумя грамматическими формами, например:

(1) ***Вы у кого сейчас лечитесь?*** Личное окончание глагола  ИТЕ (2-е лицо мн. числа)  для глагола 2-го спряжения «лечить»

(2) ***Лечитесь  лучше у N,*** это очень хороший врач. Суффикс И + окончание ТЕ мн. числа в повелительном наклонении.

Для сравнения: ***скажете – скажите***, для глаголов 1-го спряжения формы не совпадают.

2. **Нужно проверить последнюю букву Е?**  А мы разве всё можем проверить, да и что это значит – проверить букву. Даже в корне не все безударные гласные проверяются ударением, но часто контролируются по словарю.

И вот гласную Е в обоих вариантах проверить ударением нельзя – она находится **только в безударной позиции.** Тогда проверка делается не ударением, а по грамматическим справочникам, где и приводится изложенная выше информация.